# Adobe AIR default browser action

Tags: air, webkit, action, default, undo

I am working on air project based on html/javascript support. I have created undo/redo system on javascript classes, but it is interfered by browser (webkit) own undo(ctr+z) action (it focuses on last modified input element). Can I somhow turn off browser default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the default behavior of your browser but it is, as fas as I know, impossible and/or not reliable to change the browser's behavior using client-side code such as JavaScript.

You wrote that the your javascript undo command is focusing on the last modified input element, but what exact behavior are expecting?

Comment: sorry for my bad English, it is the browser that focuses on the last modified element and I do not want that the browser focus on the last modified element (it will interfer with my undo/redo history).

Comment: Do you have something online we could look at? You could use JavaScript to override the browser's focus, but I suppose you already tried that.